# Windows 10 not detecting second Monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I formatted my computer with Windows 10. I was able to use two monitors before. But now it is identifying both monitors as 1 and when I click on detect (display settings) it is giving 'Didn't detect another display' error. Both the monitors are showing same content. My windows, graphic drivers(NVIDIA), display drivers are upto date.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the *Display settings* window (where you set up your monitors).

Comment: Edited my post with image